# How to use QR Code to open AppStore or deep link an app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, qr-code

I'm currently developing an app that uses QR code to identify products. Here are the use cases:

1. If user hasn't installed the app, scanning the QR code should take them to AppStore / PlayStore to download the app.
2. If the app is installed, the user can use the app's scanner. In this case it'll extract the info (JSON format) from the QR code.

I'm not sure if QR code can achieve this. I know the first requirement needs a link to the AppStore. The 2nd requirement is just plain old JSON data. I don't know how to combine them into one QR code. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This could be done through a website as user scans the qr code it will be redirected to the website (if it's open via browser) and there's the code to redirect the url to play store or to the app.

Comment: Yes I get that part, but the other requirement is to scan the data if user is already using the app.

Comment: You can use a universal link to open your app if the code is scanned with any other scanner. If the scanner in your app reads the code you can just recognise the URL and parse out the item code.

Comment: @net-junkie you could use this (https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) library to generate and scan the qr code.

Comment: @net-junkie - what was your final solution to this?  I need to do the same and don't want to use an external service.  My platform is already generating QR Codes but I need the code to deeplink into our app or redirect to the app store if the user doesn't have the app installed.  From what I am reading it seems the only way to do this is use a URL on our own server that then determines if the user has the app on their phone, and if so intiate the custom url (deeplink) call or if not, then redirect to the app stores to installs.   Not certain though.

Comment: @rolinger My solution was quite simple: I have a QR code with URL as content. When scanned, it'll open a browser, which then redirects to AppStore or PlayStore based on OS. Once user downloaded the app, he can use the app to scan the QR code again. The app will get the data from the URL's query string.

Comment: @net-junkie
"When scanned, it'll open a browser, which then redirects to AppStore or PlayStore based on OS. "  :- How you handled this part, please explain. I am using the same functionality and able to open app if already installed, but unable to find the solution for if app is not installed. Need to redirect to respected Stores in browser.

Answer (score -2):

This is easy to do with a dynamic link from firebase https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage
Because redirecting to the stores, is the default behaviour for dynamic link

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.](/help/referencing).